# How to identify text in element using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have a question about XSLT/XPath. I am somewhat new to this and as such don't have much of a clue so forgive me if this sounds stupid.  Here is a snippet of an XML file I have:

```
<section xmlns="http://composition.companyA.com/v4" name="SOI" code=""  type="Table"  style="">
 <table xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" cols="5">
    <colspec colnum="1" colname="1"/>
    <colspec colnum="2" colname="2"/>
    <tbody>
      <tr layoutcode="" type="categoryhead" level="2" itemtype="categoryhead">
        <td colname="1">&lt;1&gt;Common stocks [Replacement]</td>  (b)
        <td colname="2"/>
      </tr>
      <tr layoutcode="" type="categoryhead" level="3" itemtype="categoryhead">
        <td colname="1">&lt;2&gt;Health care&amp;lt;softreturn&amp;gt;21.27%</td>
        <td colname="2"/>
      </tr>
      <tr layoutcode="" type="detail" level="4" itemtype="detail">
        <td colname="1"/>
        <td colname="2">Nebworth Sciences [This Tag], Inc.[$1$]</td>  (a)
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</section>
```

and an excerpt of my XSLT program:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tr/td[contains(text(),'This Tag')]">
    <xsl:variable name="GrandParentReplacementTag" select="'Asset Type'"></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="lev" select="../@level"/>
    <xsl:call-template name="replace-this">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="."/>
        <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$GrandParentReplacementTag" />
        <xsl:with-param name="by" select="../preceding-sibling::tr[@type = 'categoryhead' and @level = $lev - 2][1]/td[@colname = 'caption']/text()" />
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
```

...and what I would like to do is to be able to identify a "td" node who's text contains "This Tag" and then go to the first preceding "tr" node with the "type" attribute of "categoryhead" and has "Replacement" included in it's text, then get the text from it's child node "td" with colname = "1". I know this sounds rather convuluted and I know my sorry excuse at attempting this is pretty pathetic but I would very much appreciate any advice.

Many thanks
Alex.

Comment: You forgot to describe what problem you're facing.

Comment: When it is going through the first template, that is <xsl:template match="@*|node()"> I would like it when it comes to a node in the xml file that has text containing (in this example) 'This Tag' to run the other template <xsl:template match="tr/td[contains(text(),'This Tag')]"> instead. I know my terminology is probably all wrong but that's the best I can think of describing it. The aim is, in this example to replace the text "This Tag" with "Replacement". I have a template called replace-this which works but it never gets called because the calling template never gets triggered.

Comment: Your other template isn't looking too bad, but it won't run because of a namespace issue. Once you declare the `http://composition.companyA.com/v4` namespace (that `<section>` and everything beneath it is in) in your `<xsl:stylesheet>`, e.g. like this: `xmlns:v4="http://composition.companyA.com/v4"`, things will start to work. Just use the prefix accordingly: `<xsl:template match="v4:td[contains(text(),'This Tag')]">` and so on. Always keep an eye out for default namespaces!

Comment: Thanks, Tomalak. Looks to have done the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your entire `<section>` and everything it contains is in an XML namespace (`xmlns="http://composition.companyA.com/v4"`).

It has no prefix, so it's the default namespace and propagates to all elements within.

Therefore you must use that namespace in your XPath expressions or they won't select anything.

Using a default namespace for XPath is not possible in XSLT 1.0, so you must define a prefix<sup>**</sup>:

```
<xsl:stylesheet ... xmlns:v4="http://composition.companyA.com/v4">
```

...and use the prefix in the XPath expression:

```
<xsl:template match="v4:td[contains(text(), 'This Tag')]">
    <xsl:call-template name="replace-this">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="." />
        <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="'Asset Type'" />
        <xsl:with-param name="by" select="
            ../preceding-sibling::v4:tr[
                @type = 'categoryhead'  
                and @level = current()/../@level - 2
                and contains(., 'Replacement')
            ][1]/v4:td[@colname = '1']/text()
        " />
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
```

Note the use of the `current()` function.

---

<sup>**</sup> XSLT 2.0 fixes that, you can use [`xpath-default-namespace`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#standard-attributes) there.